# C++ Error: Undefined Symbol

Tags: c++, linker-errors

The point of my code is to be able to enter a file with blank-n somewhere within the text. It is suppose to change blank-N to a user prompted code such as (blank-N) =noun and asks the user to enter a noun but for some reason I am getting that error
So here is my code:

```
    //Author:
//
//
//
//
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using namespace std;

string getWord(ifstream &Infile, char &ch);
void getFilename(ifstream &Infile);
void getOutfile(ofstream &Outfile);
void putWord(ostream &Outfile,string word, char space);
string replacement(string word,std::string);
void printprompt(int i);
int main()
{
  ifstream filename;
  ofstream outfile;
  string file;
  string word;
  char ch;
  getFilename(filename);
  getOutfile(outfile);
  while(!filename.eof())
    {
      file =getWord(filename,ch);

      putWord(outfile,file,ch);
    }
  filename.close();
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}

string getWord(ifstream &Infile, char &ch)
{
  string wrd = "";

  Infile.get(ch);
  while(ch !=' '&& ch != '\n' && !Infile.eof())
    {
      wrd.append(1,ch);
      Infile.get(ch);
    }
  return wrd;
}

void getFilename(ifstream &Infile)
{
  string filename;
  cout<<"File for input: ";
  cin >>filename;

  Infile.open(filename.c_str());
  if (Infile.fail())
    {
      cout << "Cannot open"<<filename<<endl;
      exit(0);
    }
}

void getOutfile(ofstream &Outfile)
{
  string filename;
  cout<<"file for output: ";
  cin>>filename;
  Outfile.open(filename.c_str());
  if(Outfile.fail())
    {
      cout<< "Cannot open"<<Outfile<<endl;
      exit(0);
    }
}

void putWord(ofstream &Outfile,string word, char c)
{

  Outfile << word;
  if (c =='\n')
    Outfile<<endl;
  else
    Outfile<<" ";
}
string replacement(string word)
{
  string key[5]={"blank-N", "blank-A","blank-V","blank-P","blank-D"};
  for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
    {
      if(word.compare(key[i]))
        {
          printprompt(i);
          cin>>word;
        }

      return word;
    }
}
void printprompt(int i)
{
  switch(i)
    {
    case 0:
      cout<<"Please enter a noun";
      break;
    case 1:
      cout<<"Please enter an adjective";
      break;
    case 2:
      cout<<"Please enter a verb";
      break;
    case 3:
      cout<<"Please enter a place";
      break;
  default:;

    }
}
```

and I seem to be getting this error:

```
    Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
putWord(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char)/var/tmp//ccdj0m4f.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not know how to prevent this error from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the definition doesn't match the implementation.  In this case the parameter types don't match.

Your definition:

```
void putWord(ostream &Outfile,string word, char space);
```

Your implementation:

```
void putWord(ofstream &Outfile,string word, char c) { /* etc */ }
```

Since ostream and ofstream are different types, that's not going to compile.